# Do we have an idiom in English which roughly expresses "the strong survives and the weak dies out"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

See this paragraph,

> Some scientists say that we could just take it on the chin and let the
>   Covid19 infection move through the whole population. The strong
>   survives and the weak dies out.

Do we have an idiom in English which roughly expresses "**the strong survives and the weak dies out**"?

Comment: survival of the fittest?

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the most idiomatic (the phrase most used in casual conversation) then @Fermichem is right with "survival of the fittest."

If you are looking for something more metaphorical, then "[the law of the jungle](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/law-of-the-jungle?s=t)" would work, it means pretty much the same thing. This refers to how, in the jungle, the only supposed "law" is whatever it takes to survive.

Both "survival of the fittest" and "the law of the jungle" focus on the strong surviving and the weak dying out.

If you want to focus more on how rough life is, in general, then the terms "rat race," "vicious circle of life," and "daily grind" may be more apt.

If you want something more scientific, then "[natural selection](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/natural-selection?s=t)" would work.

Comment: I would also suggest "It's a dog-eat-dog world" as another possible common saying..  in context of the original quoted passage, though, "survival of the fittest" is probably closest.